# Exchange Partition

Tags: sql, oracle, database-partitioning

I'm a newbie at table partitioning and trying to learn.

I have two tables and I want to swap out the temp table with the final table.

So, anytime I run the below statement the entire table will copy over.

How would one create a table partition that will always capture the entire table?

Not sure if there's a proper way to handle this. Could I use a date partition or a range partition that captures all data? If so, how would that look.

`ALTER TABLE x.final EXCHANGE PARTITION (need to create) WITH TABLE x.temp INCLUDING INDEXES WITHOUT VALIDATION`

Temp: --This table has millions of rows

```
id   area   date 
1    Red    5/1/19
```

Expected Results

Final:

```
id   area   date 
1    Red    5/1/19
```

Comment: Why do you want to use exchange partition to do this?

Comment: @ChrisSaxon can I do this by a partition?

Comment: Why are you trying to use exchange partition to switch the contents of two tables? The idea behind partition exchange is to enable fast loading a of single partition

Comment: To avoid db locks.

Comment: Why are you trying to switch the whole contents of two tables?